# Java - SQLite - How to use the set of values for one column in where clause?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, where-in

I want create query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_1 in (1, 2, 3);
```

This query works in SQLite editor but I want to use it in Java.
I try to use it like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM mu_table WHERE coumn_1 in ?";
String[] args = {"(1, 2, 3)"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

But this doesn't work. The following error occurs:

> near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_1 in ?

Why is it incorrect and what is correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM mu_table WHERE coumn_1 in (?, ?, ?)";
String[] args = new String[]{String.valueOf(1), String.valueOf(2), String.valueOf(3)};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, args);
```

As it is required to pass selection argument compulsorily as string we can pass either as

```
String[]{String.valueOf(1), String.valueOf(2), String.valueOf(3)}
```

or as

```
String[]{"1", "2", "3"}
```

but it will compare as number only and not String. 
To make it compared as string we have to pass as

```
String[]{'1','2','3'}
```

but it is not required in current question context.

Comment: Sorry but i do not have any explanation for this, just i have implemented in my code i know. SO if anybody can explain please take time so whenever anybody visits this page in future for similar kind of issue can have some explanation to grasp and digest things.

Comment: This compares against three strings, not numbers.

Comment: it was just for user example. user can modify the parameters as per there requirement. Don't think it lead to negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are used for single values that are *not* to be interpreted as SQL.

Furthermore, most functions in the Android database API allow only string parameters.

This query must be used directly:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT ... IN (1, 2, 3)", null);
```